# A box within a box

Tags: python, numpy

I am attempting to solve a problem where I have a region of size = width * height and then have to find a sub-region within the region at a location x, y and of size width_1 * height_1.

The values are:

```
Region_width = 71680
Region_height = 39680
Sub_location_x=272
Sub_location_y=130
Sub_width=372
Sub_height=519
```

The code I am attempting to implement I think should be like this.

```
#Width height of box
region_width = 71680
region_height = 39680
x = 272
y = 130
sub_width = 372
sub_height = 519

#Create numpy array of width and height (This I am unsure of)
Region_array = np.array(width, height)

#Pull out sub box (This I am also unsure of)
Sub_box = Region_array[x: x + sub_width, y: y + sub_height]
```

Would really appreciate any help or insight has to how I solve the problem.

Comment: Your solution seems to be OK. What is the question? Where is the problem?

Comment: I am getting errors like:    Region_array = np.array(width, height)
TypeError: data type not understood. I do not think it is creating the array

Comment: use `np.array((width, height))` instead of `np.array(width, height)` (the input is a tuple)

Comment: The array I get back is [71680 39680] when I am looking for x =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ... 71679] y = [0, 1, 2, 3 .... 39680]

Comment: Could you detail what you mean by "have to find"? There are many ways to understand this: Do you want to draw the regions? A method to test if a given point is inside the sub region?  To select data on this sub-region from the larger dataset? ...etc

Comment: @p.strain to create the array as you need, use this: `Region_array = np.array(tuple(range(region_width)), tuple(range(region_height)))`. Explained: `range` creates iterable in size of given number with increments by 1, `tuple` makes tuple (faster version of list) from the iterable, so it can be passed to the numpy array.